# Deploy Cloud Run The instance was not started

Tags: google-cloud-platform, github-actions, google-cloud-run, cd

I create yml to deploy to Cloud Run

```
      - name: Build Docker image
        run: |
          docker build -t ${{ env.SERVICE }} .
          docker tag ${{ env.SERVICE }} gcr.io/${{ env.PROJECT_ID }}/${{ env.SERVICE }}

      - name: Authenticate Docker with GCR
        run: |
          gcloud auth configure-docker

      - name: Push Docker image to Container Registry
        run: |
          docker push gcr.io/${{ env.PROJECT_ID }}/${{ env.SERVICE }}


      - name: Deploy to Cloud Run
        run: |
          gcloud run deploy ${{ env.SERVICE }} \
            --image gcr.io/${{ env.PROJECT_ID }}/${{ env.SERVICE }} \
            --region ${{ env.REGION }} \
            --port=8080
```

I have already check about all permission on my service account
but I still got this in Cloud Run log.

```
Default STARTUP TCP probe failed 1 time consecutively for container "placeholder-1" on port 8080. The instance was not started.
```

Here is my Docker file

```
FROM golang:1.20-alpine


RUN mkdir app

ADD . /app/

WORKDIR /app

RUN go mod tidy && go mod vendor

ENV ENVIRONMENT RELEASE
ENV PORT 8080

RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o /app/my-project /app/src/

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["./my-project"]
```

I try to change port but not still work.

Comment: If you don't have any other logs, it will be impossible to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can get more info at

https://console.cloud.google.com/ > cloud build > select your region, then look at the build log

Answer (score 0):

You get more details about the error by going to the Cloud Logging Service (in Google Cloud, just search for it in the GCP search bar). You can filter the logs by time and see what went wrong.